# Как правильно обработать данные из промиса?

Tags: javascript, promise

Хочу, получить данные из API, и отобразить их на странице. Для примера беру данные из swapi вот так

```
export const getDataFunction = () => {
  return fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
  .then((data) => data.json()); 
};
```

Дальше, у меня есть класс, который отрисовывает элементы и содержит стейт, который по задумке, должен содержать объект/массив пришедший из API:

```
import {getDataFunction} from './swapiData.js';
import {DataCatalog} from './DataCatalog.js';

export class MainPage {
    constructor(element, props){
        this.element = element;
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            getData: {}
        }
        this.render();
    }
    render(){
        getDataFunction().then(res => this.state.getData = res)
        
        this.element.innerHTML = `
    <DataCatalog></DataCatalog>
    `
        new DataCatalog (document.querySelector('DataCatalog'),
            {elements: this.state.getData}
        )
    }
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что я не понимаю, как правильно добавить данные  в стейт в виде массива или объекта (не промиса). Пытаюсь вот так, но по-момему это совсем не то

```
getDataFunction().then(res => this.state.getData = res)
```

ну и как результат в теге `<DataCatalog></DataCatalog>` отрисовывается undefined, потому что класс DataCatalog в пропсах получает пустой объект.

подскажите, как правильно добавить данные в виде объекта/массива в стейт класса MainPage, чтобы потом нормально использовать их в классе DataCatalog?

Класс DataCatalog отрисовывающий что-то из API:

```
export class DataCatalog {
  constructor(element, props) {
    this.element = element;
    this.props = props;
    this.render();
  }
  render() {
        this.element.innerHTML = `
    
<div class="starship2">${this.props.elements.name}</div>`;
  }
}
```

спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, уже заметил что отсутствуют характерные для реакта вещи, и понял что коммент не нужен))

Comment: Тут сама логика не понятна: например, зачем при каждом рендере выполняется фетч... не разумнее ли вызывать рендер когда данные обновляются? Да и проблемы _с кодом_ никакой нет, он работает как должен - проблема есть с пониманием обработки асинхронных очередей и "связи" с обычным синхронным выполнением (добавление `async+await` тут легко устранит симптомы, но не устранит проблему). Попробую найти достойный связи вопрос (где эта проблема решается), т.к. вопрос явно дубликат: о "депромисификации" спрашивали тут не раз, и по идее должен быть хоть один ответ с текстом.

Comment: @yar85 у меня этот код с файлами есть и в песочнице (https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-driscoll-fqrq3?file=/main_page.js). я уже пробовал добавлять async/await к функции getDataFunction  но это не помогло. Да, может быть при каждом рендере выполняется фетч не самая классная идея, но я куда только кусок этого кода не совал. Я ж и задал вопрос, чтоб понять как устранить проблему

Comment: О том и речь, что проблема решается не сованием кода (и поэтому я не даю ответ типа "напиши тут волшебные английские словечки, и вуаля - проблема решена!"), решить ее надо пониманием того как работает цикл событий и как устроено взаимодействие очередей обратных вызовов с обычным синхронным потоком выполнения.

Comment: Увы, поиском по ruSO я не нашел ответа где эти темы хорошо объясняются, поэтому только слинкую теорматериалы (это самые доступные вводные статьи из всех что я встречал. Если не читаешь англ. - гуглоТранслейт справится): [цикл событий](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-event-loop-3dif) ► [промисы](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke); ну и после глянь [пофикшенный вариант](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-panini-vgqtq) твоего проекта в песочнице. Ответом не пишу, сорри - сейчас в работе, а для написания подробного объяснения нужно внимание.

Comment: Спасибо, смотрю!